# About usage of "yet"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I need help with the difference.
"Are you a member of the club yet?"
"Are you a member of the club ?"

What's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Using ***yet*** in this way means you are assuming or supposing that the person will join the club at some point, and you are simply asking if it has already occurred.